# SQL Server COALESCE and Group BY with NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table with some sample data:

```
City      Supplier  Month
-------------------------
Bangalore   0       NULL
Chennai     0       NULL
Chennai     2       11
Chennai     1       10
```

I am trying to get the result as

```
City     Supplier   Month
---------------------------
Bangalore   0       NULL
Chennai     2       11 
Chennai     1       10
```

I'm trying to take for each city only rows where Month is not NULL unless this the only row and then I do want it.

I tried a variety of `GROUP BY` and `COALESCE` functions, but nothing seems to work. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting on this

```
select      City,Supplier,Month

from       (select      City,Supplier,Month
                       ,count(*) over (partition by City) as cnt

            from        t
            ) t

where       Month is not null
        or  cnt = 1
```